# FECHA EN ESPAÑOL PARA PHP, BASE DE DATOS Y FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, date, fpdf

mi duda es como puedo guardar la fecha en español es decir "12 de agosto del 2020"

Yo quería que se guardara el mes (el nombre completo en español) en la base de datos pero solo se guarda de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que la fecha fuera completa ya que después se muestra en un FPDF y lo unico que he hecho es que se muestre de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y utilice el siguiente código

`$fecha = "Ciudad de México a " . date("j") . " de " . date("M") . " del " . date("Y");`

Answer (score 0):

construye un arreglo asociativo donde busques la llave por numero mes y colocas la traduccion. El objecto date en PHP es capaz de traducirte o retornar el mes completo en español pero tienes que hacer uso de setlocale.

Una pequeña idea de como lo puedes hacer con el arreglo asociativo:

```
$meses = [1 => "Enero", 2 => "Febrero" ...] ;

echo $meses[intval(date("m"))];
```